# BMS won't output voltage despite good LiPo Cells

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, gate-driving, powermosfet, bms

I have an 20 cell LiPo battery pack that is healthy at 80V in total, the BMS uses 12 MOSFETs in parallel to switch the negative terminal and they all seem healthy but won't switch on, so I can't get a voltage from the terminals, only from before the BMS at 0V and the positive terminal. I have two of these battery packs, they're e-scooter batteries, and all that was done to break them was opening the external casing to count the cells originally, although now the BMS's have been disconnected and inspected.

I don't know if this is:

- that the MOSFETs are broken, although I've measured their resistance across source-drain and they're all open circuit when unpowered, I'd love to know if there's a better way to test them if there's a way?
- or if the circuit controlling the MOSFET gates isnt sending a signal anymore. I can't measure the voltage at the gate when the BMS is attached to the battery because there's physically no space. Is there a common component that breaks and stops this gate voltage signal to the MOSFETs?
- do you know how an electrical engineer is supposed to go about diagnosing a circuit like this in general?

Any advice or thoughts would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First rule to debug: get a schematic. Sounds like you didn't design these BMSs, so it could be anything. Have you checked there is no security feature on the BMS to stop the pack working if it's been removed from the original box?

Comment: If you can't maintain the BMS, replace it with one you can.

Comment: I don't have a schematic, it's a Chinese brand BMS possibly custom made for a few thousand Fonzeralli E-Scooter batteries, I did think of a security feature like that disabling that in programming, can you tell me if that's common? @Puffafish
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Also Brian I would, but I can't find hide nor hair online of this type of board, all I know is it's made by the company BMSPOW from a bit of print on the PCB. @BrianDrummond